# Touch above the uiTabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has an UITabBarController.
I've noticed that there are like 15 pixels above the tab bar that will push the button under it. And there are like 10 more pixels that don't do anything.

The problem is that i have some button in the view that are quite close near the bar bar and when i try to touch them, the tabbar buttons get pushed.

**It seems like this is standard behavior for standard UI elements. I've noticed that the buttons from the navigation bar have the same efect**

Regards,
George

Comment: The UITabBarController should only respond to touches within the bar itself - as you should observe with other Apps.  Do you believe the behaviour you are seeing is unique to your App? If so, you'll need to post up some code so we can take a look.

Comment: @Snips I've seen this behavior on more apps. I've even heard that that's a feature.

Comment: I think Apple add in some extra px above the bar for people who have big fingers etc. I've also noticed this behaviour with the Navigation Bars and the Back Button.

Answer (score 0):

Some times I get this problem when i am using action sheets top of the tab bar. The button is in top of the tab bar is hard to click. Only part of the button is clicking. So what I am doing there is adding the action sheet from the parentview controller.

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
```

After doing this button is working perfectly. I think you can add the button to your app like this too. Hope this will help. Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.I've tried this: [myButton removeFromSuperView] [self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view addSubview:myButton];